# Automatic DrawingArea scaling on resize with (Py)GTK

Tags: python, drawing, pygtk, scaling

How can i scale the `gtk.DrawingArea` on window resize? I'm writing a code that will draw some colors in DrawingArea that will be added to an `gtk.Table` cell. I just need, that the image will be stretched in all of space of the cell.

sorry for my english.
thx

Comment: So your after a drawing area with a drawing in it and if the drawing area in the table cell is bigger than the drawing have the drawing expand to take up the new area available?

Answer (score 1):

First create the table with `homogeneous` turned off:

```
table = gtk.Table(rows=1, columns=1, homogeneous=False)
```

If `homogeneous` is not turned off, every table cell will be as wide and tall as your DrawingArea.

To attach the DrawingArea to the table:

```
  table.attach(child, left_attach, right_attach, top_attach, bottom_attach,
           xoptions=EXPAND|FILL, yoptions=EXPAND|FILL, xpadding=0, ypadding=0)
```

Leave `xoptions` and `yoptions` as `EXPAND|FILL` to make the DrawingArea expand. If the table is also set to expand, the default when doing `toplevelWindow.add(table)`, then the DrawingArea should automatically resize when the window is.

See this site for more info: [pygtk table documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-PackingUsingTables.html)

Comment: it doesn't work. the `gtk.DrawingArea` on create calls `self.set_size_request(w,h)` and on the window resize the DA is the same w,h